# Make the tags and select list active without using Form Builder in laravel?

Tags: forms, laravel-5

I am unable to make a dropdown select list using the below code to generate a location select dropdown where database table =>location and column=>name

```
<select name="location">
        @foreach ($locations as $loaction)
        <option value="{{ $loaction->name }}">{{ $loaction->name }}</option>
        @endforeach 
</select>
```

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation? What is expected output? What have you tried so far? I can see `$locations` but I'm not sure what you mean by `database table =>location and column=>name`.

Comment: Can u please let us know what are you getting on the page.
Is it giving any error or its blank.